# change date format in extjs

Tags: extjs

I am new to extjs and want to change date format.

I am fetching date from database. My date is in format -> YYYY-m-d,

and  want to change this format to d-m-YYYY.

.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are the `Date` and `Ext.Date.format` classes for this. (Version 4.1)

```
var dt = new Date('2012-05-31')
'formatted Date:' + Ext.Date.format(dt,'d-m-Y') // 31-05-2012
```

Comment: hello Alax, I have done like this----{
                                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                    dataIndex: 'DateAdded',
                                    text: 'Added',
          renderer: function(value){
           var dt = new Date(value);
                                            var val = Ext.Date.format(dt,'d-m-Y') 
           return val;
          }
                                }  but its displaying my date as ---->   NaN-NaN-0NaN

Comment: my date is ----   2012-06-27 17:46:47  and i want to display it as  27-06-2012

Comment: I alert "value" here. Its showing correct date, but When i tried to alert "dt".Its saying "Invalid Date".

Comment: thanks alax , done....  but its showing correct value only by using (2012-06-27). and if i use ( 2012-06-27 17:46:47 ), it gives error

Comment: You'll have to check with the Ext documentation what constructors are allowed as for the string argument. Make sure the time is also in the correct format.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using `Ext.data.Model` you should look at [Ext.data.Field#dateFormat](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-dateFormat)
to correctly converting received data.

Working with grids, you can look at the column's renderer [Ext.grid.column.Column#renderer](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer)
and use [Ext.util.Format#dateRenderer](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.util.Format-method-dateRenderer) as a renderer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in a template use the following:

```js
{MyDate:date("M")}
```

Use the following [link](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/modern/Ext.Date.html) to find all the Extjs formatting as of ExtJs6.2

```js
 Format      Description                                                               Example returned values
 ------      -----------------------------------------------------------------------   -----------------------
   d         Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros                             01 to 31
   D         A short textual representation of the day of the week                     Mon to Sun
   j         Day of the month without leading zeros                                    1 to 31
   l         A full textual representation of the day of the week                      Sunday to Saturday
   N         ISO-8601 numeric representation of the day of the week                    1 (for Monday) through 7 (for Sunday)
   S         English ordinal suffix for the day of the month, 2 characters             st, nd, rd or th. Works well with j
   w         Numeric representation of the day of the week                             0 (for Sunday) to 6 (for Saturday)
   z         The day of the year (starting from 0)                                     0 to 364 (365 in leap years)
   W         ISO-8601 week number of year, weeks starting on Monday                    01 to 53
   F         A full textual representation of a month, such as January or March        January to December
   m         Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros                     01 to 12
   M         A short textual representation of a month                                 Jan to Dec
   n         Numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros                  1 to 12
   t         Number of days in the given month                                         28 to 31
   L         Whether it&#39;s a leap year                                                  1 if it is a leap year, 0 otherwise.
   o         ISO-8601 year number (identical to (Y), but if the ISO week number (W)    Examples: 1998 or 2004
             belongs to the previous or next year, that year is used instead)
   Y         A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits                         Examples: 1999 or 2003
   y         A two digit representation of a year                                      Examples: 99 or 03
   a         Lowercase Ante meridiem and Post meridiem                                 am or pm
   A         Uppercase Ante meridiem and Post meridiem                                 AM or PM
   g         12-hour format of an hour without leading zeros                           1 to 12
   G         24-hour format of an hour without leading zeros                           0 to 23
   h         12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros                              01 to 12
   H         24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros                              00 to 23
   i         Minutes, with leading zeros                                               00 to 59
   s         Seconds, with leading zeros                                               00 to 59
   u         Decimal fraction of a second                                              Examples:
             (minimum 1 digit, arbitrary number of digits allowed)                     001 (i.e. 0.001s) or
                                                                                       100 (i.e. 0.100s) or
                                                                                       999 (i.e. 0.999s) or
                                                                                       999876543210 (i.e. 0.999876543210s)
   O         Difference to Greenwich time (GMT) in hours and minutes                   Example: +1030
   P         Difference to Greenwich time (GMT) with colon between hours and minutes   Example: -08:00
   T         Timezone abbreviation of the machine running the code                     Examples: EST, MDT, PDT ...
   Z         Timezone offset in seconds (negative if west of UTC, positive if east)    -43200 to 50400
   c         ISO 8601 date represented as the local time with an offset to UTC appended.
             Notes:                                                                    Examples:
             1) If unspecified, the month / day defaults to the current month / day,   1991 or
                the time defaults to midnight, while the timezone defaults to the      1992-10 or
                browser's timezone. If a time is specified, it must include both hours 1993-09-20 or
                and minutes. The "T" delimiter, seconds, milliseconds and timezone     1994-08-19T16:20+01:00 or
                are optional.                                                          1995-07-18T17:21:28-02:00 or
             2) The decimal fraction of a second, if specified, must contain at        1996-06-17T18:22:29.98765+03:00 or
                least 1 digit (there is no limit to the maximum number                 1997-05-16T19:23:30,12345-0400 or
                of digits allowed), and may be delimited by either a '.' or a ','      1998-04-15T20:24:31.2468Z or
             Refer to the examples on the right for the various levels of              1999-03-14T20:24:32Z or
             date-time granularity which are supported, or see                         2000-02-13T21:25:33
             http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime for more info.                         2001-01-12 22:26:34
   C         An ISO date string as implemented by the native Date object's             1962-06-17T09:21:34.125Z
             [Date.toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)
             method. This outputs the numeric part with *UTC* hour and minute
             values, and indicates this by appending the `'Z'` timezone
             identifier.
   U         Seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)                1193432466 or -2138434463
   MS        Microsoft AJAX serialized dates                                           \/Date(1238606590509)\/ (i.e. UTC milliseconds since epoch) or
                                                                                       \/Date(1238606590509+0800)\/
   time      A javascript millisecond timestamp                                        1350024476440
   timestamp A UNIX timestamp (same as U)                                              1350024866
```